# If an airport does not have a KCM access point can crew with KCM credentials use TSA Pre-Check lanes?

Tags: airport-security, tsa-precheck, cabin-crew

From [Knowncrewmember.org/rules](https://Knowncrewmember.org/rules):

[image]

To clarify my question, I want to emphasize that this blurb states that this is "When selected for additional screening" ***at a KCM checkpoint***, which not every airport with airline services has.

If there is no KCM checkpoint then you can't be "*selected* for additional screening".

Are crew who are part of the KCM program authorized to use TSA pre-check lanes in the total absence of a KCM checkpoint at the airport both in and out of uniform, only in uniform, or not at all?  Please find an official source. I have failed to find anything other than random back and fourths on internet forums and non-official websites such as Knowncrewmember.org.

Comment: You might have more luck asking on a forum like [PPRuNe](https://www.pprune.org/trending.php) if you don't get an answer here.

Comment: As far as I can tell, knowncrewmember.org is at least semi-official. The Known Crewmember program is a joint thing between ALPA (pilot union), A4A (airline trade association), and TSA. ALPA’s website refers to knowncrewmember.org as the program’s site. So while it’s not a government source, it’s not an unofficial source either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the document that comes with the id badge, "TSA PreCheck® at most airports with no KCM® Access Points"

[image: Known Crewmember flyer]